# Using Diebold-Mariano test to compare predictive errors in non-time-series?

Tags: time-series, data-mining, prediction, diebold-mariano-test

I understand that the DM test is established for time series data, but could I still apply the test for non-time-series data? Could I simply replace the autocorvaiance part of the test statistics with zero to obtain the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the Diebold-Mariano test, this should definitely be OK. (I hope anyone who disagrees and downvotes leaves an explanation so we all learn from this.)

Specifically, I recommend [this "20 years later" paper by Diebold](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236#.VTSfraM6lUQ), along with subsequent Comments and a Rejoinder in the same JBES issue. It explains in equation (1) the single core assumption of the test: that the loss differential between your two predictions have constant mean and be covariance stationary. (Which may in fact be a *sufficient* condition but not a *necessary* one.) Unless you have some rather strange prediction methods, any reasonable analogue should be true for your losses, so the result should still be valid.